# How do I get Dwarf Therapist to work with the latest Dwarf Fortress?

Tags: dwarf-fortress

I just downloaded the latest DF(0.31.12) and the latest Dwarf Therapist(0.5.7). When I open Dwarf Therapist, it says it doesn't

> ...know how to talk to this version of
>   Dwarf Fortress!(checksum:0x4c4c32e7)

When I look in the etc/memory_layouts/windows folder, I don't see a file for 0.31.12; the latest one I see is for 0.31.10. Does one exist?

Comment: Here's the file for 31.11 http://code.google.com/p/dwarftherapist/issues/detail?id=278

Comment: This question should not have been closed as too localized; instead it should have been edited to apply to DF in general. The actual problem is that dwarf therapist needs to be recoded for each new version of Dwarf fortress, since new versions add new job roles for dwarves. So this problem is not specific to one version of DF, but is an ongoing issue with all versions. The easiest solution is to download dwarf fortress inside one of the 'lazy newb packs', since in those packs the version of dwarf therapist included matches (is compatible with) the version of dwarf fortress in the package.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

http://code.google.com/p/dwarftherapist/wiki/MappingNewVersions, all the way at the bottom.

```
[info]
checksum                = 0x4c4c32e7
version_name            = v0.31.12 (graphics)

[addresses]
translation_vector      = 0x016da41c
language_vector         = 0x016da3ec
creature_vector         = 0x0169575c
dwarf_race_index        = 0x014c0f1c

[offsets]
word_table              = 0x0058

[dwarf_offsets]
first_name              = 0x0000
nick_name               = 0x001C
last_name               = 0x0038
custom_profession       = 0x006c
profession              = 0x0088
race                    = 0x008C
flags1                  = 0x00F8
flags2                  = 0x00FC
sex                     = 0x0110
id                      = 0x0114
recheck_equipment       = 0x021C
birth_year              = 0x0298
current_job             = 0x0390
physical_attrs          = 0x0464
states                  = 0x0684
souls                   = 0x0790
likes                   = 0x07A0
labors                  = 0x07BC
happiness               = 0x087C

[soul_details]
skills                  = 0x01FC
traits                  = 0x0224

[job_details]
id                      = 0x0008
on_break_flag           = 0x0011

[position_offsets]
token                   = 0x0000
flags                   = 0x0020
general_name_singular   = 0x00E8
general_name_plural     = 0x0104
male_name_singular      = 0x0158
male_name_plural        = 0x0174
female_name_singluar    = 0x0120
female_name_plural      = 0x013C
# 2 bytes each...
custom_color_red        = 0x037E
custom_color_green      = 0x0380
custom_color_red        = 0x0382

[valid_flags_1]
size                    = 1
1/name                  = "Not from around these parts"
1/value                 = 0x80000000

[invalid_flags_1]
size                    = 7
1/name                  = "a zombie"
1/value                 = 0x00001000
2/name                  = "a skeleton"
2/value                 = 0x00002000
3/name                  = "a merchant or diplomat"
3/value                 = 0x00000040
4/name                  = "outpost liason"
4/value                 = 0x00000800
5/name                  = "an invader or hostile"
5/value                 = 0x00020000
6/name                  = "an invader or hostile"
6/value                 = 0x00080000
7/name                  = "an invader or hostile"
7/value                 = 0x000C0000

[invalid_flags_2]
size=2
1/name                  = "dead, Jim."
1/value                 = 0x00000080
2/name                  = "from the Underworld. SPOOKY!"
2/value                 = 0x00040000
```

Comment: http://code.google.com/p/dwarftherapist/issues/detail?id=278